# SQLite dropping zeros

Tags: sqlite

I'm using google wrapper (sqlite3pp) to insert a char array that contain some zeros. The problem that is the SQLite is dropping the zero and the next elements after it.

```
char array[11] = {1,2,3,4,5,0,3,4,0,6,7};

sqlite3pp::command cmd(db, "INSERT INTO messages (id, payload) VALUES (?, ?)");

cmd.bind(1,index);
cmd.bind(2,&array[0],sizeof(array));
```

This code only insert: 1 2 3 4 5

The payload type is varchar.

Any idea?

Comment: How exactly are you checking the value in table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite3pp defines, among others, these two overloads for the `bind()` function:

```
int bind(int idx, char const* value, bool fstatic = true);
int bind(int idx, void const* value, int n, bool fstatic = true);
```

You want to use the second one with explicit length, but the first one is selected, while `sizeof(array)`, evaluated to be `11`, is truncated to `bool` value `true` and passed as `fstatic` instead of size. The wrapper then thinks the value is a plain NUL-terminated string and thus stores just the part till the first zero.

---

You can help the compiler to select the right version e.g. by providing the implicit parameter like so:

```
cmd.bind(2, &array[0], sizeof(array), true);
```

(Or `false` when the array will be deallocated before the query is done executing.)

---

Additionally, there can be problems with reading the rows as well - e.g. the default sqlite3pp getter for std::string won't work with binary zeroes and the content needs to be retrieved explicitly like this:

```
payload.assign(static_cast<const char*>(i->get<const void*>(2)), i->column_bytes(2));
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you quick answer. I tried that but the zero continues to be dropped.

Comment: Hm, it works for me. How do you check if it is inserted? Couldn't it be dropped when reading it? E.g. I needed to dump the table as `SELECT HEX(payload) FROM ...` to see it correctly.

Comment: You are correct. It's dropping when reading. 
std::string payload;

sqlite3pp::query qry(db, "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY ROWID ASC LIMIT 1");
sqlite3pp::query::iterator i = qry.begin();
(*i).getter() >> idx >> payload;
Any ideia?

Comment: OK, so you need to do something like `payload.assign(static_cast<const char*>(i->get<const void*>(2)), i->column_bytes(2));`. And the previous fix was needed nevertheless, the payload was getting truncated when storing too.

Comment: Changed to payload.assign(static_cast<const char*>(i->get<const void*>(1)), i->column_bytes(1)); and worked fine :) Thank you very much!!

Comment: I'm trying to find this option. Where should I click?